# Get запрос с параметрами Python

Tags: python, api, url, requests

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне сформировать get запрос и в параметрах отдать тип запроса (query_type ), чтобы принимающая сторона поняла что передавать и отдала мне нужные данные ? 
Всего лишь два типа запроса у меня . 
query_type = 1 
query_type = 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться пакетом `urllib`.

***Пример:***

```py
import urllib.parse as urlparse
from urllib.parse import urlencode


# URL, на который собираетесь отправлять запрос
url = 'http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=question'

# Параметры запроса
params = {
    'tag': 'python',
}

url_parts = list(urlparse.urlparse(url))
query = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(url_parts[4]))
query.update(params)

url_parts[4] = urlencode(query)

# Готовый URL
new_url = urlparse.urlunparse(url_parts)  # http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=question&tag=python
```

**UPD:**

Или библиотекой `requests`.

***Пример:***

```py
import requests


# URL, на который собираетесь отправлять запрос
url = 'http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=question'

# Параметры запроса
params = {
    'tag': 'python',
}

# Ответ
r = requests.get(url=url, params=params) # r.url = 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=question&tag=python'
```

Comment: можно ли это сделать через request ?

Comment: @СергейЯнченко Обновил ответ, попробуйте.

Comment: Спасибо, все в порядке

Comment: @СергейЯнченко Раз так, то отметьте ответ как правильный, пожалуйста.